# Namespace x does not exist in the <project> namespace, even if the reference is added to the project

Tags: c#, tfs, build, visual-studio-2015

After merging my development branch with release branch in TFS(Visual Studio),
I am seeing this error in many places.

[image: Namespace does not exist error]

But, the reference is already added to the project.

[image: Reference already exists]

After, I remove the reference and add it again, the error goes away. The references are of other projects in the solution.

- Is there any precaution I can take to avoid manually removing/adding
  several references again?
- Is there a way to refresh(for lack of a better word) the added
  references to resolve these type of errors?

Appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: Did you check not to miss any brackets (`{` and `}`)?

Comment: @KnorxThieus, Sorry, I didn't get your point. I made no changes to code as such, since there was no conflict after merge operation.

Comment: Did all your team members have this issue? Which version of TFS and VS are you using? Do you try on another machine?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT  Yes, I have seen this on multiple machines. I am using VS 14.0.24720.00 Update 1 and Visual Studio Team Services(couldn't find a version number).